# Apply text based styling done for a single post in WPBakery to all posts / create a template out of it

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, templates

I work on a project with several custom post types. One of these post types is called BSP. For one single specific BSP (called test BSP) I created a whole design with WPBakery, as shown on this image:

Showing the WPBakery elements
[image]

The same template as plain text
[image]

**Question:**

I have several other BSP custom posts. While I can just copy the plain text of this test BSP and paste it to the other custom posts of type BSP, how can I make this the default template? I'm more specifically looking for a way to have this template automatically being applied to any new post of type BSP I create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. It is very easy and rather obvious.

**To save the template:**

First click on the template icon above the edit page of the blog post you want to copy the template from.
[image]

Next: go to the my templates tab and save the template as a custom template
[image]

**To make the saved template the default template:**

Click on the WPBakery tab and select the template for that specific post.
[image]